# Repeated background image after hitting a button meant for ajax

Tags: css, asp.net, background-image

How can i avoid repetitiveness of a background image in an asp.net web page? 
Here is the code:

```
<body style="height: 150px"  background="url">
```

upon execution of an ajax control, this image gets displayed in two frames in the background.

Comment: "Here's the code" - where?

Comment: Markdown was messed up.  Should show correctly once my edit gets approved

Answer (score 1):

Just define style on body:

```
style="background-repeat: no-repeat;"
```

Comment: when i do this, the next frame comes with white background....i want only one frame with a single background image.

Answer (score 1):

```
<body style="height: 150px; background-image:url('yourimg'); background-repeat: no-repeat;">
```

Comment: the image is not displayed

Comment: I KNOW this works.  Look at this http://jsfiddle.net/acsteitz/2c2h6/.  You must have a typo.

Comment: Did you look at the jsfiddle in my previous comment?  Can you please edit your original question and post your ACTUAL html.